# HTML5 Fitting To Screen Resolution

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've been looking around for a solution to this with very little luck. I'm not very good at HTML or CSS. I understand basics, but I need what I am making in HTML 5. So I would really appreciate any assistance.

I used this site to get kind of what I'm going for [Here](http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/replicating-the-swipe-gesture-iphone-gallery-for-mobile-web-html5-part-1/).

It supposed to be an HTML5 app that can be displayed on Android, iPhone, and iPad. It really doesn't have many features. Mainly just the ability to swipe to flip pages just like that link shows. My issue is I can't get the images and it as a whole to fit whichever screen it is on. It seems like it is hard coded to work at iPhone size, but when displayed on an iPad it takes up a small portion of the screen. I'll post his code below so you don't have to go there to see it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Swipe Gesture - Gallery</title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="slideContainer">
      <li>
        <img src="img/1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/3.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/4.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/5.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/6.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js">
</script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
}

#wrapper
{
  overflow:hidden;
}

#wrapper ul
{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s linear;
}

#wrapper ul li
{
  float:left;
}
#imgFit {
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 320px;
   max-width: 768px
}
```

JS:

```
 (function() {
var swipey = {
slideContainer: null, //<ul> element object that holds the image slides
wrapper: null, //meant for masking/clipping
slides: null, //array of all slides i.e <li> elements
distanceX: 0, //distance moved in X direction i.e left or right
startX: 0, //registers the initial touch co-ordinate
preferredWidth: 0, //dynamic variable to set width
preferredHeight: 0, //dynamic variable to set height
direction: "", //direction of movement
timer: null, //timer that set starts when touch starts
timerCounter: 0, //counter variable for timer
isTouchStart: false, //boolen to chk whether touch has started
maxDistance: 0, //maximum distance in X direction that slide container can move
currentDistance: 0, //current distance moved by slide container through translate

initSwipey: function() {
//scroll the window up to hide the address bar of the browser.
window.setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 100);
//get all the instances of the HTML elements
swipey.wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
swipey.slideContainer = document.getElementById("slideContainer");
swipey.slides = slideContainer.getElementsByTagName("li");

//for iPhone, the width and height
swipey.preferredWidth = 320;
swipey.preferredHeight = 416; //510 for android
//setting the width and height to our wrapper with overflow = hidden
swipey.wrapper.style.width = swipey.preferredWidth + "px";
swipey.wrapper.style.height = swipey.preferredHeight + "px";
//setting the width to our <ul> element which holds all the <li> elements
swipey.slideContainer.style.width = swipey.slides.length * swipey.preferredWidth + "px";
swipey.slideContainer.style.height = swipey.preferredHeight + "px";
//calculating the max distance of travel for Slide Container i.e <ul> element
swipey.maxDistance = swipey.slides.length * swipey.preferredWidth;
//initialize and assign the touch events
swipey.initEvents();
},
initEvents: function() {
//registering touch events to the wrapper
swipey.wrapper.addEventListener("touchstart", swipey.startHandler, false);
swipey.wrapper.addEventListener("touchmove", swipey.moveHandler, false);
swipey.wrapper.addEventListener("touchend", swipey.endHandler, false);
},
//funciton called when touch start event is fired i.e finger is pressed on the screen
startHandler: function(event) {
//stores the starting X co-ordinate when finger touches the device screen
swipey.startX = event.touches[0].pageX; //.changedTouches[0]
//timer is set on
swipey.timer = setInterval(function() { swipey.timerCounter++; }, 10);
swipey.isTouchStart = true;
event.preventDefault(); //prevents the window from scrolling.
},
//funciton called when touch move event is fired i.e finger is dragged over the screen
moveHandler: function(event) {
if (swipey.isTouchStart) {
swipey.distanceX = event.touches[0].pageX - swipey.startX;
//move the slide container along with the movement of the finger
swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + (swipey.distanceX + swipey.currentDistance) + "px, 0,0)";
}
},
//funciton called when touch end event is fired i.e finger is released from screen
endHandler: function(event) {
clearInterval(swipey.timer); //timer is stopped
if (swipey.distanceX > 0) {
swipey.direction = "right";
}
if (swipey.distanceX < 0) {
swipey.direction = "left";
}
//the following conditions have been discussed in details
if ((swipey.direction == "right" && swipey.currentDistance == 0) || (swipey.direction == "left" && swipey.currentDistance == -(swipey.maxDistance - swipey.preferredWidth))) {
swipey.comeBack();
}
else if (swipey.timerCounter < 30 && swipey.distanceX > 10) {
swipey.moveRight();
}
else if (swipey.timerCounter < 30 && swipey.distanceX < -10) {
swipey.moveLeft();
}
else if (swipey.distanceX <= -(swipey.preferredWidth / 2)) { //-160
swipey.moveLeft();
}
else if (swipey.distanceX >= (swipey.preferredWidth / 2)) { //160
swipey.moveRight();
}
else {
swipey.comeBack();
}

swipey.timerCounter = 0; //reset timerCounter
swipey.isTouchStart = false; //reset the boolean var
swipey.distanceX = 0; //reset the distance moved for next iteration
},
moveLeft: function() {
swipey.currentDistance += -swipey.preferredWidth;
swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransitionDuration = 300 + "ms";
//using CSS3 transformations - translate3d function for movement
swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + swipey.currentDistance + "px, 0,0)";
},
moveRight: function() {
swipey.currentDistance += swipey.preferredWidth;
swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransitionDuration = 300 + "ms";
swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + swipey.currentDistance + "px, 0,0)";
},
comeBack: function() {
swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransitionDuration = 250 + "ms";
swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction = "ease-out";
swipey.slideContainer.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + swipey.currentDistance + "px, 0,0)";
}
}; //end of swipey object
window.swipeyObj = swipey; //expose to global window object
})();

swipeyObj.initSwipey(); //invoke the init method to get started
```

I added the imageFit one because the images were not scaling to the screen size and that was my attempt. It seems that it goes for the max-width no matter what. If there are any better ways of doing this or if you know a fix I would really appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried setting "width=device-width" on the viewport meta?

Comment: Have you tried changing the javascript preferredWidth to ipad resolution?

Comment: @DerekGutierrez Just gave that a shot. Stretched the whole thing out across. Both my Android phone and my iPad had the image displayed stretched.

Comment: I tried setting preferredWidth = device-width. Same with height. It fits the screen better on both devices now except now its scroll down the list instead of side swipping. It also doesn't cover the whole screen there is a white bar on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this chunk of code:

```
//for iPhone, the width and height
swipey.preferredWidth = 320;
swipey.preferredHeight = 416; //510 for android
```

To:

```
//Auto-detect resolution via javascript:
swipey.preferredWidth = screen.width;
swipey.preferredHeight = screen.height;
```

This will use javascript to auto-detect the screen resolution.

Then the script will multiply the li width by the number of li elements to adjust the slideContainer ul to fit content:

```
//setting the width to our <ul> element which holds all the <li> elements
swipey.slideContainer.style.width = swipey.slides.length * swipey.preferredWidth + "px";
swipey.slideContainer.style.height = swipey.preferredHeight + "px";
//calculating the max distance of travel for Slide Container i.e <ul> element
swipey.maxDistance = swipey.slides.length * swipey.preferredWidth;
```

If the above doesn't work, also try removing #imgFit style and see if it fixes the scrolling.  problem. It may be interfering with something.

Also, by setting the image widths and heights to 100% with the inline styling they will look out of proportion when loaded on different resolutions. If you want the images to stay a specific proportion, you can try just setting the width to 100%, then the browser should scale it properly.