# Set screen resolution for html5 video player

Tags: javascript, video-player

I need an API to find screen resolution in JavaScript then pass it html5 video player. I tried
`//document.write(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);`
But its not working for me.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524241/html5-fitting-to-screen-resolution

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242086/how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-with-javascript